# The diving board and the black window

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, magic

This is a short story, not a novel.

I read this story in a collection in possibly 1959, but I do not know when this book was published.  It had a great effect on me.  I cannot remember the writer's name, or the title of the story.

It concerns two young men who are looking for work.  They read the wanted columns, and they find an ad for a doctor.  They go to meet him, and this doctor has a diving board (I seem to remember "diving board", but it could be "platform" -- I'm not sure) facing a black window.  He wants them to jump into this unknown "world" via the diving board, and come back to report to him what they find there.  One of the young men tries this, but he never comes back.  So the second young man also does it.

He discovers the body of his friend.  This friend has fallen among some boulders because he had not jumped far enough.  And so this second young man looks around for a while.  It is a land of perpetual twilight with backwards writing on some cans and food packages.  There is a radiance, and electrical look to parts of the sky.  Our young man realizes where he is, because one is from a power generator, and the other is from the University.  So he figures out where he is, climbs up the boulders past his friend's body, gets into the doctor's window, forces the doctor to jump off the diving board to see for himself, and that's the end of the story.

Do you recognize this?  I really liked it, and I would like to read some more by this writer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Just to clarify though, is this a novel or a short story? You added the [novel] tag to the question, but your description makes it sound like you're looking for a short story.

Comment: Do you remember whether it was explicitly called a "diving board" or might have been described as a "platform" or something like that?

Comment: This is obviously the same as [1950s short story from kids' sci-fi anthology: diving board and black window](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183908/1950s-short-story-from-kids-sci-fi-anthology-diving-board-and-black-window-sp). Sadly that question has no answers.

Comment: @JohnRennie - Also asked here; https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/fv9fp8/diving_board_doctor_and_black_window_a_short/

Comment: @lisaxx Please [edit] your post with any additional information about the story, even if in response to a comment. If you wish to directly reply to a comment with information that is not pertinent to the question itself you can click "add a comment" and reply to a particular user by typing "@" followed by the username. Please take a look at the [help] to get acquainted with the site, and feel free to stop by [chat] if you have any question about how to use the site -- some of the chat regulars are sure to help.